# How to replace numeric characters

Tags: python

In every name in `names`:

```
names = ['name_9', 'name_xyz', 'name_10', 'name_11']
```

I want to replace the numbers with a single '*' star character so the final result would look like:

```
result = ['name_*', 'name_xyz', 'name_*', 'name_*']
```

(Please note that some of the names in `names` could contain no digits (such as 'name_xyz'. And a single star `*` character replaces any number regardless on how many digits the number contains... so a number `4` is replaces with a single `*` star and the number `444` is also replaced with a single `*` star).

How to get it done?

Comment: `[re.sub('\d+', '*', name) for name in names]`

Comment: @YSelf Nope it dosent. It replaces all of them

Comment: You are right. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import re as

```
import re
```

then add a for loop with a regex

```
for x in names:
     print(re.sub('\d+','*',x))
```